# PHP Counting Negative Numbers and Bold Only Even Numbers

Tags: php, numbers, bold

On a form, I used PHP to display every number from 1 to the entered number. For example, if I enter 10 on the form, it displays 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. Now, I want it to be able to handle negative numbers by counting up to 0 (-10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0) and make every even number in the results bold, e.g., 2 4 6 8 10, etc.). I've searched exhaustively for the answers without any luck. How would any of you suggest doing this? My code for the first part is displayed below. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
$num = $_POST['num'];
$limit = $_POST['num'];

echo "<pre>";   
do {
echo ($counter).'<br>';
$counter++;
} while ($counter <= $limit);
echo "<pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Enable error reporting... the above code should spit something out.

Comment: if(ereg("[13579]+$",$counter))

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
<?php
$num = $_POST['num'];
$limit = $_POST['num'];

echo "<pre>";   
do {
if( $counter % 2 == 0 )
{
    echo "<strong>" . $counter . "</strong><br />";
}
else
{
    echo ($counter).'<br>';
}
$counter++;
} while ($counter <= $limit);
echo "<pre>";
?>
```

**Solution 1**
Ok, some more information about the %. This is a [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). It gives you back the remaining number if you divide it by the mod number. For example

```
0 % 2 = 0
1 % 2 = 1
2 % 2 = 0
3 % 2 = 1 this because 3 / 2 = 1 and a bit,
          you can't divide the last 1 completely by 2. So remain 1
4 % 2 = 0
```

**Solution 2**
Like crush said, you can use `$counter & 1`. What does this do?

If you look at a number bitwise. You want to AND it wit 1.

```
Bitwise number 2 = 0010 AND it with 0001 and your return will be 0000 (zero).
Bitwise number 3 = 0011 AND it with 0001 and your result will be 0001 (one).
```

If you ceep that going and only check the last bit, you can see if it is a even number. More about [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: `if ($counter & 1)` is much faster way to tell if even/odd than using modulo operator.

Comment: Correct. But I'm using some explanation for if he wants to do something like 1 of 3 or 1 of 4. Added your answer to my question. With some more explaination.

Comment: I actually ran some tests on this. It doesn't seem to be remarkably faster in PHP 5.4+. It's a significant optimization in C++, and other languages though. I'm guessing that PHP must do some optimization.

Comment: That's kinda strange, since bitwise operations are way easier than modulo.

Comment: Oops. I was overwriting one of my variables that I used to track the start time...lol. So, interesting results after fixing that. Modulo is actually beating the bitwise now.

Comment: Results on `10,000,000` iterations: `$i & 1 == 0: 0.52367997169495` and `$i % 2 == 0: 0.48078989982605` ... kind of crazy. Wonder what is up with PHP's bitwise operations?

Comment: Really intesting that dividing actually takes less time than checking 1 bit.

Comment: Well, apparently I'm retarded. I changed it to `$odd = ($i & 1)` from `$even = !($i & 1)` and now it outperforms modulo by about .1s on 10,000,000 iterations. I was doing two bitwise operations before lol. Dno what I was smoking.